# AJAX error when calling it inside a function into JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm facing a weird error using JavaScript.

I have a file add_account.js in my project that it throw JQuery error, when my AJAX function is inside a function.

It occurs the same problem when I use components like bloodhound and typehead.

By the way it's not throwing even the error set up by AjaxSetup. It stops and no alert.

**Error:** 
 TypeError: e is undefined
     setRequestHeader:function(e,t)
       {var n=e.toLowerCase();return x||(e=v[n]=v[n]...
        jquery-....min.js (line 5, col 11629)

```
var testAjaxRun = function(){

$.ajaxSetup({
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            alert('Time out error.');
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            alert('Ajax request aborted.');
        } else {
            alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    }
});

$.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          url: "../controllers/fde.php", 
          success: function(data) {
             alert('success');
              return data;
          }
        });
 //...

}
// outside function and in the end of file

 $(document).ready(function() {
  testAjaxRun();
});
```

If I remove the AJAX instructions to outside function it works normally.

**Error:** 
 TypeError: e is undefined
     setRequestHeader:function(e,t)
       {var n=e.toLowerCase();return x||(e=v[n]=v[n]...
        jquery-....min.js (line 5, col 11629)

Any idea of this problem? All the rest inside the script is working perfectly.

It is project I'm migrating from Java to PHP. The javascript file into the Java Project works normally as well.

Answer (score 0):

Folks,

I found the problem. Actually there is nothing wrong with the javascript.

The problem was that the project had another file.js that had this instruction which screwed up my ajax call.

Then I commented _jquery.init and all works.  After 2 nights without sleeping and testing all the other things I got the error. :)

```
_jquery.init()

    _jquery = {
        init: function () {
             $(document).ajaxSend(function (e, xhr, options) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader(sync.csrfHeader, sync.csrf);
    });
   }   };
```

Java project probably is treating this field, but I don't need it for now.